# Partner's money from abroad

Tags: taxes, canada

I am Canadian and my common law partner is Mexican. We want to buy property in Canada with a mortgage that will be under my name only. Every month she withdraws money from her account in Mexico as her contribution to our purchase. Do I need to declare this money to the government or will I be taxed on it later on? Or is it just considered a tax free gift between spouses?

Comment: technically spousal money is not gifted to each other, it is a "common" funds, not sure if that is somehow different in Canada; perhaps the term common law partner might be the stickler here